# php file cannot be found on root ONLY (IIS6)

Tags: php, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I'm running PHP on my win2003 IIS6 server.

I have installed everything to the point I CAN browse php files (wordpress).
However when i try to access a root php file (on the root of the web site) then i have a file not found exception.

Any hint ?
Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was messy configuration of the IIS that caused this.